# Using Sitecore link Manager in scriban script

Tags: sxa, link-manager, scriban

I have a general link that is linking to an item in Sitecore.
**Path to linked item -->** `/sitecore/content/home/pageItemWithLayout`

I am using the below scriban script below to render the item link.

```
<a href = "{{i_item.Link.Target}}"  target="_blank">Some item Link </a>
```

and HTML is rendered

```
<a href="/sitecore/content/home/pageItemWithLayout" target="_blank">Some item Link </a>
```

is there a way to access a friendly URL for this Sitecore item in scriban similar to how we can use Sitecore LinkManager `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(itempath)` to get the friendly url?

The output required after scriban render is

```
<a href="/pageItemWithLayout" target="_blank">Some item Link </a>
```

This item could also be present in a microsite as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use field renderer like:

```
{{ sc_field i_item 'Link' [['target', '_blank']] }}
```

Comment: is there a way to make this link uneditable in experience editor?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But you can always try to write you own scriban function, see examples here https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2020/05/13/Rendering-Links-with-Scriban/

Comment: Thanks @Marek. we ended up writing our own scriban function to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the field render option as Marek described and you can also use `sc_link` as described here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html

Your code would be:

```
<a href = "{{sc_link i_item.Link.Target}}"  target="_blank">Some item Link </a>
```